# how to solve path fill color

Tags: javascript, svg

Here is my code,

```
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path stroke="#C4C24A" fill="red" d="M50 50 L100 50 L100 100 L150 100" />
</svg>
```

in this code i have used fill and stroke while run this the fill and stroke both's are applied. here i have used MoveTo LineTo LineTo...

another one ,

```
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path stroke="#C4C24A" fill="red" d="M50 50 L100 50 
  M100 50 L100 100 
  M100 100 L150 100" />  
</svg>
```

in this code i have used MoveTo LineTo MoveTo LineTo.. Same output displayed here but fill color was not applied..

why? and in first example i need to show the output without applying fill color what can i do without changing path and fill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example might clarify it:

```html
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path stroke="#C4C24A" fill="red" d="
    M50 50
    L100 50
    L100 100
    L150 100
    M250 50
    L300 50
    L300 100
    L350 100" />
</svg>
```

Path will create a polygon if you have more than two points. With two points you make a line. Each time you lift your pen by using `M`, you start from scratch.

So in your first example, you are making a four-point polygon. In your second example, you are making three disconnected lines. You can fill a four-point polygon, but a line is a bit too thin to fill.